# How to get Spring XD to deploy a predefined set of streams and taps on startup

Tags: spring-xd

Is there a way to launch a set of steams and taps that have been defined when a new instance of spring xd is launched?

The scenario is this: We've done some prototyping on our dev systems, but now when we'd like to build and release this to a test team. We'd like to automate most of the background work and the user needs to just worry about the output from the streams and not have to worry about the streams or their definitions or their deployment.

To facilitate this is there any runtime configurations we can use?

UPDATE: Our current approach involves writing a shell script to make some rest calls to the Spring API to create and deploy the required streams.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The shell maintains a log of user commands:

```
spring-shell.log
```

You can edit it after creating your stream(s) (or create a file with shell commands) and then use the script command:

```
xd:>script foo.xd
```

or

```
$ bin/xd-shell < foo.xd
```

(the .xd suffix is not required, the file name can be anything).

**EDIT** (comment below)...

> This does come with the caveat that `bin/xd-shell < foo.xd` will run all commands regardless of success or failure, and `xd-shell --cmdfile foo.xd` will terminate execution with an exit code immediately should a command fail.

Comment: Thanks again Gary. Was this detail in the documentation by any chance? I looked around but didn't see anything.

Comment: I am not sure if it's explicitly mentioned in the XD docs, but the XD shell is based on the [Spring Shell](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell#readme) and it's mentioned there. Also you can type `help` to get a list of all commands.

Comment: you can also use  `$ xd-shell --cmdfile foo.xd`

Comment: There is some info in the [docs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki/Shell#executing-a-script) for future ref

Comment: In distributed mode, would this mean I try $ xd-container --cmdfile foo.xd

Comment: No; the command file is not passed to the container, it is passed to the shell (which uses ReST to talk to the admin node). The admin node then selects which container to deploy it on.

Comment: I've been using info a lot more than I've used help. I think that's exactly what the doctor ordered!

Comment: This does come with the caveat that `bin/xd-shell < foo.xd` will run all commands regardless of success or failure, and `xd-shell --cmdfile foo.xd` will terminate execution with an exit code immediately should a command fail.